# How do I pass in user inputed variables into a constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

I just need some help with this program.
The user has to enter in the id,password,the number of max tries & the number of max uses.
And they have to go into a constructor...
Could someone help me pass them into the constructor?
I'm using java.
Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LoginPw{


 public static void main(String[] args){
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter in your id and password");
  int idnum = reader.nextInt();
  int password = reader.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Enter in the max number of tries");
  int maxtries = reader.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Enter in the number of max uses");
  int maxuses = reader.nextInt();
  PwLogin pwl = new PwLogin(idnum,password,maxtries,maxuses); 

 }}
class PwLogin{

  public PwLogin(int id, int pw){
   //assumes max num of tries is infinite. denote by value of 0.
   this(id,pw,0,0); //call the 4-argument constructor w/ maxTries & maxUses defaulted as zero(infinite)
  }
  public PwLogin(int id, int pw, int tries){
   //assumes max number of uses is infinite. denote by value of 0.
   this(id, pw, tries,0); //Call the 4-argument constructor with maxUses defaulted as zero (infinite)
  }
  public PwLogin(int id, int pw, int tries, int uses){
   // Now set the 4 class variables from the passed-in arguments
   this.idnum =id; 
   this.password = pw;
   this.maxtries=tries;
   this.maxuses=uses;

  }  

 }
```

Comment: Your code is already doing what you asked. Can you explain the problem you're having?

Comment: oh the publicPwLogin( int id, int pw, int tries, int uses){
doesnt work for the "this.idnum=id;" or any of the this.'s
and i don't know how to fix it
or why its wrong...

Comment: Apart from the missing `idnum`, `password`, etc fields, it looks ok :/

Comment: what do you mean by im missing the idnum, passowrd, etc fields?
is that why the "this.etc"'s aren't working?
& how would i fix this?
Thanks! :)

Comment: Right, just like in Mark's answer. I recommend grabbing a good Java book if you're not familiar with such basic concepts :) Some suggestions can be found on SO - just search for 'java book' or something similar

Comment: Thank you everyone sooo much!!! :) :) :]

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare member variables in Java:

```
class PwLogin{

    private int idnum; 
    private int password; 
    private int maxtries; 
    private int maxuses; 

    public PwLogin(int id, int pw){
        etc...
```

Comment: So this would be the user inputted numbers?
Like the ones i have reading in my main?
do they have the same value as the userinputted ones in main?

Comment: Initially they are set to zero, but after you set them with the line 'this.idnum = id;' then they are set to the same value as you entered.